# How to get memory and cpu usage by a Spark application?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I want to get the average resource utilization of a spark job for monitoring purposes, how can I poll the resource ie cpu and memory utilization of a Spark Application.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pull the logs from YARN

**Command line :** `yarn application -logs {YourAppID}` You can get the applicationID from the stack of the spark job or from the `yarn application -list` command or from UI too. More on the yarn commands are [here](https://maprdocs.mapr.com/52/ReferenceGuide/YARNcommands.html)

**FROM UI :** If you are using Cloudera you can see from `http://${LOCALHOST}:7180/cmf/services/17/applications` you can get to the DAG with `http://${LOCALHOST}:8088/cluster`

Answer (score 1):

You may check the stderr log for completed Spark application. 
Go to Yarn Resource Manager. Click on an application ID and then "Logs" on the right side of appattempt_* line.
Scroll to Log Type:stderr and click "Click here for the full log". Look at the log for something like this:

```
"yarn.YarnAllocator: Will request 256 executor containers, each with 5 cores and 8576 MB memory including 384 MB overhead"
```